# How do I change a div class first-letter with the first-letter selector?

Tags: selector

My html code looks like this:

`<div class="entrybody"> Some text/content </div>`

I want the first letter between this piece of code (for example `"Some text"`) to become alot much bigger every time I post something on my blog. Here is a picture of what I mean:

> http://i58.tinypic.com/9hierp.png

How do I do this? I have tried with 
`.entrybody::first-letter` but it doesn't work...

Comment: post your code (css / html) in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zb522v2g/1/    {{ entry.body }} is a piece of code that makes the content appear. In this code, all the content is included (pictures and text), div.entrybody::first-letter doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

You were using :: to access the psuedo element.

Put only one :

```
.entrybody:first-letter
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zb522v2g/2/

Read more about this here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-better-paragraph/